# How do I prove the total moment of horizontal and vertical components of a force is independent of point of application along the line of action?

Tags: forces, vectors, moment

How do I prove the total moments of the horizontal component, $\underline{x}$, and vertical component, $\underline{y}$, of a force, $R$, around a point, $A(\overline{x},\overline{y})$, is independent of their point of application, $B(x,y)$, along the line of action, $y=mx+c$, of said force, $R$?

I guess I have to take an expression for the total moment and reduce it to a constant, independent of $x$ and $y$. I tried but failed.

[image]

Comment: Edited the formatting in your question to use the available MathJax (latex-style) formatting. Please check that the edited version accurately reflects what you want to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it myself. Guess I gave up too easily the first time.

total moment around the point, $A(\overline{x},\overline{y})$,
$= \underline{x}(\overline{y}-y) - \underline{y}(\overline{x}-x) $
$= \underline{x}(\overline{y}-(\frac{\underline{y}}{\underline{x}})x - c) - \underline{y}(\overline{x}-x) :$ substitute $y$ with $(\frac{\underline{y}}{\underline{x}})x + c$
$=\underline{x}.\overline{y} - \underline{y}.x - \underline{x}.c - \underline{y}.\overline{x} +\underline{y}.x$
$=\underline{x}.\overline{y} - \underline{x}.c - \underline{y}.\overline{x}$
$=$ constant

Comment: Well done! I thought you might have wanted something like this. Terribly long-winded but good practice in working with components.

Answer (score 0):

Go back to the definition of *moment of force about a point*.

Magnitude of moment about O
= magnitude of force x Perpendicular distance from O to line of action of force

That's it! The line of action of the force is what matters, not the point of application. Just drop that perpendicular!

But I'd guess you're looking for something more complicated...